Using NetTopologySuite and EF Core to insert objects with SQL Server Geography types
I have a legacy SQL Server that is using a geography datatype for a column in a table to store data with X, Y, Z, and M coordinates.
Legacy C# projects used the System.Data.Entity.Spatial library and SqlServerTypes native dll with the DbGeography type to save these records in the database.
I am creating a new utility in .NET 8 to insert data, and do not want to take a dependency to the native DLLs, so I am trying to leverage the NetTopologySuite and the MultiPoint object to do so.
private MultiPoint CreateMultiPoint(DateTime departureTime, IEnumerable<Position> positions)
{
     var coordinates = new List<Coordinate>();
     var points = new List<Point>();

     var geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);

     foreach (var position in positions)
     {
         var coordinate = new CoordinateZM(position.Lon, position.Lat, position.Fal,
             (position.Svd - departureTime).TotalSeconds);

         coordinates.Add(coordinate);

         var point = new Point(coordinate) { SRID = 4326 };
         points.Add(point);
     }

     return new MultiPoint(points.ToArray(), geometryFactory);
}

When saving the object with this multipoint in the DbContext in EF Core, the following exception occurs:

The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 ("@p0"): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type geography. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.

It seems that the multipoint trying to be inserted is a MultipointZ and possibly is missing the M value.
I've tried a variety of different ways of constructing the geometry factory and could use some help, as none of them seem to work.

I haven't played with NTS, but doesn't it only support geometry types? SQL Server handles the geography and geometry types seperately.

Try swapping the lat and lon
